# How to Make a Specific Boxplot Invisible in ggplot2 While Keeping the Spacing for Group Comparisons?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working with ggplot2 in R to create a plot that contains multiple boxplots and point ranges. I would like to make the boxplot for one particular group ("Group A" in my example) invisible while maintaining its space, so the other boxplots don't shift and the point ranges stay aligned with their corresponding boxplots.

I've tried setting the values for "Group A" to NA, which removes the boxplot, but it also shifts the remaining boxplots, which is not the desired outcome.

I want to keep the boxplots for the other groups in their original positions, effectively leaving a blank space where the "Group A" boxplot would have been so that only the pointrange is visible.

Here's the reproducible example code:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Example data
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  Group = factor(rep(c("Group A", "Group B", "Group C", "Group D"), each = 50)),
  Value = c(rnorm(50, mean = 10), rnorm(50, mean = 15), rnorm(50, mean = 20), rnorm(50, mean = 25))
)

# Create a point range data set similar to Weighted_means in your case
point_range_data <- data.frame(
  Group = c("Group A", "Group B", "Group C", "Group D"),
  fit = c(10, 15, 20, 25),
  lower = c(5, 10, 15, 20),
  upper = c(15, 20, 25, 30)
)

# Plot
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Group, y = Value)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Group), outlier.shape = NA, position=position_dodge(0.8)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Group A" = NA, "Group B" = "blue", "Group C" = "green", "Group D" = "red")) +
  geom_pointrange(data = point_range_data, aes(x = Group, y = fit, ymin = lower, ymax = upper, color = Group), 
                  position=position_dodge(0.8), size = 0.5) +
  theme_minimal()

p
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your box plots invisible you could use a `"transparent"` fill for Group A and to get rid of the outline use `after_scale` to set the color to `"transparent"` too:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Group, y = Value)) +
  geom_boxplot(
    aes(
      fill = Group,
      color = after_scale(
        ifelse(fill == "transparent", "transparent", color)
      )
    ),
    outlier.shape = NA,
    position = position_dodge(0.8)
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = NULL, values = c(
    "Group A" = "transparent", "Group B" = "blue",
    "Group C" = "green", "Group D" = "red"
  )) +
  geom_pointrange(
    data = point_range_data, aes(
      x = Group, y = fit,
      ymin = lower, ymax = upper, color = Group
    ),
    position = position_dodge(0.8), size = 0.5
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(color = NULL, fill = NULL)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- `filter()` to remove data for `Group A` in `df` and `point_range_data`
- `scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)` to keep position for `Group A` in x axis
- `scale_y_continuous(limits=...)` to keep original point ranges

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Example data
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  Group = factor(rep(c("Group A", "Group B", "Group C", "Group D"), each = 50)),
  Value = c(rnorm(50, mean = 10), rnorm(50, mean = 15), rnorm(50, mean = 20), rnorm(50, mean = 25))
)

# Create a point range data set similar to Weighted_means in your case
point_range_data <- data.frame(
  Group = c("Group A", "Group B", "Group C", "Group D"),
  fit = c(10, 15, 20, 25),
  lower = c(5, 10, 15, 20),
  upper = c(15, 20, 25, 30)
)



# Plot
df %>%
  filter(Group != "Group A") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Group, y = Value)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Group), outlier.shape = NA, 
               position=position_dodge(0.8)) +
  geom_pointrange(data = point_range_data %>% filter(Group != "Group A"), 
                  aes(x = Group, y = fit, ymin = lower, ymax = upper, color = Group), 
                  position=position_dodge(0.8), size = 0.5) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(point_range_data$lower[point_range_data$Group == "Group A"], 
                                max(point_range_data$upper))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Group A" = NA, "Group B" = "blue", "Group C" = "green", "Group D" = "red")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("Group A" = NA, "Group B" = "blue", "Group C" = "green", "Group D" = "red"))
```