# How to Hide Specific Category's Boxplot in ggplot2 While Preserving Dodging for Other Categories So PointRange is still Visable

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Problem**

I'm encountering a challenge with ggplot2 in R. I need to create a grouped boxplot where each category has multiple models compared side by side using position_dodge. However, for one specific category named "Weighted Actual", I want to completely hide its boxplot (no outline, no fill, no points) while still preserving the space it would occupy. This is crucial to maintain the correct alignment of the remaining categories' boxplots.

**Here's what I need:**

The "Weighted Actual" boxplot should be invisible.
The space for "Weighted Actual" must be preserved to keep the alignment of other boxplots.
The dodging for other boxplots should remain unaffected.
The pointrange for the "Weighted Actual" should remain visable in its original position

**What I've Tried**

I've tried several methods, including setting the alpha to 0, using ifelse within aes() to assign NA to the fill and color for "Weighted Actual", and adding a dummy layer for spacing. Despite these attempts, I end up with either a visible boxplot outline for "Weighted Actual" or affecting the dodging layout of other boxplots.

**Expected Outcome**

The expected outcome is that the boxplot for "Weighted Actual" will not be visible at all, no outline, no fill, no whiskers, but the pointrange for "Weighted Actual" will be clearly displayed, and the alignment of the other boxplots and pointranges will be unaffected.

Here's a reproducible example of what I've tried:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Dummy data for reproducibility
set.seed(42)
df <- expand.grid(Category = c("A", "B", "C"),
                  Model = c("Model 1", "Model 2", "Weighted Actual"),
                  replicate = 1:25)
df$Value <- rnorm(nrow(df), mean = rep(c(10, 15), each = 100), sd = 2)

# Dodge width for separation within categories
dodge_width <- 0.9

# Base plot
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Category, y = Value, fill = Model)) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(dodge_width), outlier.shape = NA)

# Add pointranges for illustration (not part of the actual problem)
p <- p + geom_pointrange(aes(y = mean(Value), ymin = mean(Value) - sd(Value), ymax = mean(Value) + sd(Value), color = Model),
                         position = position_dodge(dodge_width), size = 0.5)

# Attempt to hide the "Weighted Actual" boxplot while maintaining the position for dodging
p <- p + scale_fill_manual(values = c("Model 1" = "blue", "Model 2" = "green", "Weighted Actual" = NA)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = NA)))

# View the plot
p
```

The image below illustrates the current output, where "Weighted Actual" is still partially visible:
[image]

I would greatly appreciate any advice or solutions that can help me achieve this result in ggplot2. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Could you clarify how this question differs from your [last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78209397/how-to-make-a-specific-boxplot-invisible-in-ggplot2-while-keeping-the-spacing-fo/78210526#78210526)? The answer I offered also applies to this case: Set `"Weighted Actual" = "transparent"` in `scale_fill_manual` and add `aes(color = after_scale(if_else(fill == "transparent", "transparent", color)))` to `geom_boxplot`.

Comment: Sorry, I just needed to play around with your example. It worked like a charm. Thank you very much! I accepted your answer on the other one.

Comment: Quick question: What would the code be if I wanted to switch the fill and the color. Such that the boxplot would populate with color parameter, be transparent but still show the point range?